# Why do I keep getting SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: node.js, backend, mern

I am trying to take a csv file and convert it to a json using csvtojson. I keep getting a syntax error please help

```
const csvfilepath = require("../csvfiles/usethis.csv");
const csv         = require('csvtojson');

router.post('/upload', (req,res) => {
    csv()
    .fromFile(csvfilepath)
    .then((jsonObj)=>{
      console.log(jsonObj)
      })
  })
```

My usethis.csv looks like this

```
Date,Time,CoreUsage ,TotalCPU ,MemoryClock
13.10.2021,53:54.4,13.6,13.6,1796.6
13.10.2021,53:56.5,12.7,12.7,1796.6
13.10.2021,53:58.5,21.3,21.3,1796.6
13.10.2021,54:00.5,11.2,11.2,1796.6
13.10.2021,54:02.6,5.5,5.5,1796.6
13.10.2021,54:04.6,13.1,13.1,1796.6
13.10.2021,54:06.7,14.6,14.6,1796.6
13.10.2021,54:08.7,16.9,16.9,1796.6
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
13.10.2021,53:54.4,13.6,13.6,1796.6
     ^^^^^

Syntax Error: Unexpected number
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module. Require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/users/blake/desktop/Fullmern/routes/benchmark.js:12:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module. Load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module. Require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/users/blake/desktop/Fullmern/server.js:19:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes on each value

```
Date,Time,CoreUsage,TotalCPU,MemoryClock
"13.10.2021","53:54.4","13.6","13.6","1796.6"
"13.10.2021","53:56.5","12.7","12.7","1796.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
Date,Time,CoreUsage ,TotalCPU ,MemoryClock
```

with

```
Date,Time,CoreUsage,TotalCPU,MemoryClock  //remove extra space
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `require()` a `.CSV` file like you are trying to do here:

```
const csvfilepath = require("../csvfiles/usethis.csv");
```

Require knows how to do two things:

1. Load and run a file of Javascript.
2. Read and parse a .JSON file (if any only if, the file has a `.json` file extension).

So, `require()` is trying to parse your CSV as Javascript and immediately runs into a Javascript syntax error because .CSV formatted data is not valid Javascript (no surprise there).

If you want to read a .CSV file into memory, then use `fs.readFileSync()` or `fs.promises.readFile()` (depending upon whether you want a synchronous or asynchronous operation).

If you want to read and parse the .CSV file, then use one of the many modules on NPM for reading/parsing CSV files.